# How can I assassinate someone and make it look like an accident?

Tags: dnd-4e, assassin

I was recruited by an Assassin's guild when my party of five was out of town, and now I have to assassinate someone and make it look like an accident. The problem is that my party has to contact my target for another mission that I am also involved in, and they don't know I have to kill the guy. How can I murder him in secrecy?
You see, the guild master said that nobody could know what I do inside the guild. I think that means that everything i do should be in absolute secret. My character is very good at sneaking, perception, acrobacy and athletics, but the target seems to be very difficult to kill, as he is a drow. My concern is that the town is guarded by some sorcerers and a giant Ogre, so I don't really know how to perform the assassination, because the target is in the same Inn as my party is and we have to get some items from him

Comment: Plot twist: OP is planning to do this in real life.
Not a plot twist: very interesting question. What setting are you playing in?

Comment: Does it have to look like an accident to *everyone*, or is it OK if the other PCs learn what is going on?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site... This is quite borderline for our site rules; we require that questions be focused and directed, and to provide enough requirements to enable voters to recognize which answers are better than others. See the [Tour] for more details. So while I’m not *quite* ready to close this question, I’m not sure it’ll get great answers, either. Posting more information about the town, the guild, the target, your own character, both as a character and mechanically, will help a lot to give answerers ideas and ensure that their suggestions are actually useful to you.

Comment: @GAX those kinds of details definitely belong *in the question*, add a few sentences along those lines to an edit. Might also help if the *DM* gave you any specifics beyond the in character stuff.

Comment: There you go hahaa. I'm sorry, this is the first time i use this site, should have read the tour first =D

Comment: Anyway, his words were exactly these: And make it look like an accident. He didn't say anything about the target

Comment: The DM said I can't ask him anything about the target nor how to perform the assassination, because he got some things planned for me. "You have to do it from what you already know"

Comment: I think waxeagle's answer sums it up as best as possible but what you are trying to do is outside the mechanics of 4e (except if the GM makes it a skill challenge) as such there needs to be an agreement made with the GM about expectations and other players as players should know what is occurring.

Comment: Aaah, forgot to tell earlier that the target is a drow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With stealth, GM buy in, and probably not without the knowledge of your fellow *players* (though their characters don't have to know).

Here's the first thing. Take the GM aside and ask him about the expectations for this mission.  He gave it to you, he certainly has and idea about how he thinks it's supposed to go down. He can help you, especially where the mechanics are concerned (the mechanics for killing a monster/NPC outright aren't particularly useful for an assassination, he may have something else in mind).

Second, let's hope your character's strong in bluff and stealth, he's going to need both of them to slip away unnoticed and pretend like he doesn't know what happened.

Lastly, it does *not* behoove you for your fellow players to be in the dark on this. Talk to them, this is an important plot point and while their *characters shouldn't necessarily know what happened* their players can, and should. Especially if they need to talk to him for something else plot wise.

From a mechanics perspective, to kill someone outright (if they have monster stats, or PC stats for that matter), the way to kill them outright is to *either* fight them one on one (if they are an equal level foe, you will have a big chance of losing), OR to sneak into their bedroom at night and coup de grace them. Though to be clear, a coup de grace in 4e is only an outright kill if you deal at least their bloodied value in damage (it's an auto crit though, so that should help). Again, it's important to talk to your DM about whether he is planning to use a separate rules set (Specifically something along the lines of a skill challenge perhaps) to accomplish this *rather* than using the combat rules since they break down in situations like this.